# Не срабатывает setinterval и не передается массив

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Необходимо, чтобы новости на сайте считывались из файла и менялись через 1-2 с. В литературе рекомендуют использовать setInterval js. Файл считывается в массив в php, после чего нужно передать i-й элемент в Js. Рекомендуют использовать json_encode($mas). Массив формируется, но не передается.

Текст программы:

```
<script>
<?
$s = getcwd();
$d = dir($s . "\\news");
if (!is_file($d->path . "\\news")) {
    echo ($d->path . "\\news");
} else {
    $f = fopen($d->path . "\\news", "r") or die("Ошибка при открытии файла \n");
    $list = file($d->path . "\\news");
    $i    = 0;
    $flg  = 0;
    $cnt  = count($list);
    if ($cnt > 5)
        $cnt = 5;
    $k   = 0;
    $mas = array();
    for ($j = count($list) - 1; $j > count($list) - $cnt - 1; $j--) {
        $mas[$k] = $list[$j];
        $k++;
    }
    echo "var cnt=3;
                  var i=0;";

    echo json_encode($mas);
    exit;
    fclose($f);
}
?>
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(mas);
setInterval(Gen_zag(mas,cnt),1000);
</script>
```

Функция Gen_zag определена выше:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function Gen_zag(mas, cnt) {
        zag = mas[i].substring(0, mas[i].indexOf('='));
        txt = mas[i].substring(mas[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        document.write("<h3> НОВОСТИ: </h3> <br> ");
        document.write("<h3> " + zag + " </h3> <br>");
        document.write("<p> " + txt + "</p> <br><br>");
        i++;
        if (i > cnt) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Не получается, а json_encode я правильно использую?

Comment: Ну и наверно надо еще делать echo "var mas = ".json_encode($mas);

Answer (score 3):

setInterval надо использовать не так. В этом случае вот так:

```
setInterval(function() { Gen_zag(mas,cnt); },1000);
```

Так как у тебя, можно использовать только в случае, если вызываемая функция не принимает параметров

Answer (score 3):

Первый аргумент setInterval должна быть функция без параметров. Т.е. вот так:

```
setInterval(function(){
    Gen_zag(mas,cnt);
},1000);
```

Но можно также вернуть функцию без параметров из Gen_zag(mas,cnt):

```
function Gen_zag(mas, cnt) {
    return function(){
        zag = mas[i].substring(0, mas[i].indexOf('='));
        txt = mas[i].substring(mas[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        document.write("<h3> НОВОСТИ: </h3> <br> ");
        document.write("<h3> " + zag + " </h3> <br>");
        document.write("<p> " + txt + "</p> <br><br>");
        i++;
        if (i > cnt) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval( Gen_zag, 1000, mas, cnt );
```

Comment: Правда, что ли?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp - почитай вот тут внимательно
Или вот тут - http://javascript.ru/setInterval

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Это не работает в IE, но там есть fix, еще вопросы?

И вообще - я такой подход реально использовал, в т.ч. под ИЕ, ровняться на стандарт 100500 летней давности это не для меня, если вам нравится - вперед :) Браузеры, старше 18и уже давно поддерживают модель вида:

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);

Comment: ну, я просто только начала изучать и php и js - 1-я попытка сайта. Решила начать разбираться на примере. Поэтому, если хотя бы что-то рабочее получится, уже буду рада и буду изучать дальше, без простого не бывает сложного. Всем спасибо за помощь!